# Android layout shadow

Tags: java, android, user-interface, layout, shadow

Hi I have been searchin for a solution on how I can make something like this possible. I am able to make two seperate views and make one grey an the other white but there isn't the same feel. Google uses a kind of shadowy effect in the white one. Is there a library that will allow me to do so?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you're probably talking about **elevation**, its a lollipop feature.
[Material Design: Objects in 3D space - Elevation](http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/objects-in-3d-space.html#objects-in-3d-space-elevation)

there are many ways to replicate it on older versions of android, you could make your own png [background image.](http://fireworks.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/drop-shadow-settings-win.png)

get creative with it, it's a lot of fun